# Any application to play song when headset is inserted

Tags: linux, arch-linux, music

Is there any script which plays the song when the headset is inserted in Arch Linux?  That would make it more like android phone.

Comment: have a poke around in udev, there should be some sort of event when the headset is detected,

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around. I switched to xfce desktop. Then, play the amarok in the background. Change the volume to lower. Plug the headset and increase the volume. Next, time when you insert the headset it will automatically increase the volume and you can listen the song.